# Django use values or values_list with non related models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this both models:

```py
class GeneCombination(models.
    gene = models.ForeignKey(Gene, db_column='gene', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_constraint=False)

class Gene(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

I know it's not the best model schema, it has to be like that due to business rules. I'm getting the values from `GeneCombination` model and some fields from `Gene` model. Now, It could be that a gene is not present in Gene model, in that case **that rows are being filtered when I use `values` of `values_list` methods, which is what I want to prevent**.

This query is returning 31 elements: `GeneCombination.objects.select_related('gene').values('gene')`

But this query is returning 27 elements (**is filtering the 4 elements** whose gene does not exist in Gene table): `GeneCombination.objects.select_related('gene').values('gene__type')`

How could I get empty values in case that It doesn't exist and prevent the rows to be filtered?

Thanks in advance and sorry about my English

Comment: That has nothing to do with empty values. For empty values It returns  **None**. I just checked it `[{'contact__name': u'Firstname Lastname'}, {'contact__name': None}]`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I'm not getting None, row are directly ommited

Comment: Apparently has to do with `db_constraint`. Django says: _If this is set to False, accessing a related object that doesn’t exist will raise its DoesNotExist exception._

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that! Unfortunatelly I can't to apply db_constraint as I have missing elements in Gene model and it breaks the migrations